# Why does Python Choropleth map not display colors?

Tags: python-3.x, folium, choropleth

I would like to create a Choropleth map in Python using Folium library.

**This is the dataset:**

df_new_count2

Reviewer Country    Count   Original Number Percentage

0   Greece  191 3352    0.056981

1   Belgium 338 5991    0.056418

2   Germany 429 7843    0.054698

**The Json file used is the following**: https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/DV0101EN/labs/Data_Files/world_countries.json

**This is the code I used:**

```
world_map = folium.Map(location=[40, 0], zoom_start=1.5)
```

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data='https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/DV0101EN/labs/Data_Files/world_countries.json',

```
    name='choropleth',

    data=df_new_count2,

    columns=['Reviewer Country','Percentage'],

    key_on='feature.properties.name',

    fill_color='YlOrRd',

    fill_opacity=0.7,

    line_opacity=0.2,

    legend_name='Percentage of people'
).add_to(world_map)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(world_map)
```

world_map

The map is displaying but everything is black, the colors are not showing.

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66hmc.png)

Does anyone know what the issue might be? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Please include any code and data as text in the question, not by linking to screenshots.

Comment: Done, but I think it was clearer before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
import folium

# create dataframe
df_new_count2 = pd.DataFrame([['Greece', 0.056981], ['Belgium', 0.056418], ['Germany', 0.054698]], columns=['Reviewer Country','Percentage'])
df_new_count2

# plot map
world_map = folium.Map(location=[40, 0], zoom_start=1.5)
folium.Choropleth(geo_data='https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/DV0101EN/labs/Data_Files/world_countries.json', name='choropleth',
    data=df_new_count2,
    columns=['Reviewer Country','Percentage'],
    key_on='feature.properties.name',
    fill_color='YlOrRd',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Percentage of people'
).add_to(world_map)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(world_map)
world_map
```

Result:
[image]

It only colors the countries for which data is available in the dataframe.
Can you validate your dataframe contains data for the countries selected?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it does not change anything...

Comment: The dataset comes from Kaggle and I used pandas to read it. I wanted to filter only the rows with 'Original Number' greater than 2000 so I used the following piece of code: df_new_count2=df_new_count[df_new_count['Original Number'] > 2000], this is the last instruction before creating the map...

Comment: I just updated m answer. The map only colors the countries for which data is available in the dataframe. Can you validate your dataframe contains data for the countries selected?

Comment: Hi Rene, I figured out why it wasn't working. All the strings with the names of the countries had blank spaces, so I had to trim them. Thank you very much for your time and cooperation!